# Symfony2 do not use pdo, but the error i have search, need to use pdo

Tags: symfony, pdo, doctrine

I do not use any PDO on my project, but i got this error.

```
An exception occurred while executing 'DELETE FROM bidang_pekerjaan_mahasiswa WHERE id_mahasiswa = ?' with params [14148]:

SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined
500 Internal Server Error - DBALException
1 linked Exception: PDOException »
```

i have search what's the problem, and it told me that i should give a PDO param

```
->setParameter('id', $id, \PDO::PARAM_INT)
```

well,, it is okay, do not have any error yet. But i have problem with the others on my controller.. i got a notice

```
Notice: Array to string conversion in /myProject/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php on line 784
```

and my repository cannot work at all to insert database

All of my project goes right, but when i need to add some function in one of my repository, i got error like that.
Please help me, i need to solve that as soon as possible

Comment: As for the `Array to string` error: Can you please post the query that triggers this error? Otherwise it's hard to see the actual problem.

Comment: Btw, “Please help me, i need to solve that as soon as possible” doesn't make anything happen faster. I just makes you look like a crybaby. ;)

Comment: As opposed to looking like a bully?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DBAL connection class provided by Doctrine2 is actually a child class of `PDO`, if you're using a PDO driver.

You can check your currently used driver looking at the `database_driver` in your `app/config/parameters.yml` file. Yours should be `pdo_mysql`.

To get access to the connection/PDO instance, you can use the `doctrine` service.

```
// $ServiceContainer is your services container; if you have an instance
// of Doctrine or the entity manager, you can use them directly, of course
$Connection = $ServiceContainer->get('doctrine')->getManager()->getConnection();
```

Then you can use the `$Connection` like any other PDO instance.

See also: http://doctrine-dbal.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/configuration.html

**

As for the `Array to string conversion` problem, this is something different: You're passing a parameter which is expected to be an string, but you pass an array. Unfortunately, you don't post the actual query, so it's not possible to say what exactly the problem is.